# Oracle Universal Connection Pool for JDBC with GlassFish v3.x

Tags: java, glassfish, ucp

Is it possible to integrate Oracle UCP with GlassFish v3.x to allow a web application to connect to an Oracle RAC database and benefit from Fast Connection Failover (FCF), run-time connection load balancing, and connection affinity?